# How to create split single dataset into multiple sets in CPLEX OPL using array or tuple of user-defined tuples

Tags: arrays, tuples, cplex, opl, websphere

I have a model with multiple time periods and I receive some data in the format of a tupleset with a time dimension. Thus, the original tupleset is the superset of the tupleset required for each time period. I also have an array of integers which represent the time periods. In preprocessing, I need to iterative over this data and analyze each time period separately. I believe I can reduce preprocessing time significantly by splitting the original tupleset into its time-period based subsets and then iterate each of these independently during preprocessing.

In dat file:

```
timeSet = {1 2};
dataset = {
//<attribute1, attribut2, timePeriod>
<a,b,1>
<a,c,1>
<a,b,2>
<a,b,2>
};
```

In mod file:

```
{int} timeSet = ...;
tuple data {string attribOne; string attribTwo; int time;};
{data} dataset = ...;
```

I don't know ahead of time how many time periods there will be, so if I can't split up the tupleset on the fly, then I would need to do something like this:

```
execute{
   for(var t in timeSet) {
      for(var r in dataSet) {
         if(r.Time == t) {
            //call a function that executes on r
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However, I want to avoid the above code because it requires iteration over the entirety of the dataSet for each time in timeSet. If I can split out dataSet into multiple tuples or arrays based on the value of the time field, then I could replace the above with something like the following:

```
 execute{
   for(var t in timeSet) {
      for(var r in dataSetsCollection[t]) {
         //call a function that executes on r
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to create an item such as dataSetsCollection from the code above? I attempted to do so with a tuple:

```
tuple TdataSetsCollection {data row;};
{TdataSetsCollection} dataSetsCollection = {<ds> | ds in dataset : ds.Time = t};
```

and with an array:

```
tuple TdataSetsCollection {data row;};
TdataSetsCollection DataSetsArr[t in TimeSet] = [t : ds | ds in datasets, t in TimeSet : ds.Time == t];
```

Neither of the above worked so I'm currently stuck.

I have [cross-posted this question](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=aafd7668-a7a1-4323-88f1-49a110e7854d&ps=25#repliesPg=0).

Comment: In general, if you cross-post a question to multiple fora, it is ideal to declare all of the copies in each location. This makes it easier for readers to determine whether a question has already been answered, and thus helps them avoid duplicate effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use slicing:

.mod

```
{int} timeSet = ...;
tuple data {string attribOne; string attribTwo; int time;};
{data} dataset = ...;

{int} computedTimeSet={d.time | d in dataset};
{data} dataSetPerTime[t in computedTimeSet]={d | d in dataset : d.time==t};

execute
{
  writeln(dataSetPerTime);
}
```

.dat

```
timeSet = {1 2};
dataset = {

<a,b,1>
<a,c,1>
<a,b,2>
<a,d,2>
};
```

gives

```
 [{<"a" "b" 1> <"a" "c" 1>} {<"a" "b" 2> <"a" "d" 2>}]
```